Is this subclass of transcendental function studied in the literature?
By definition, an analytic function $f(x)$ is an algebraic function if there exists a rational non-zero polynomial $P(x,f(x))$ such that $P(x,f(x)) = 0$. If $f(x)$ is not transcendental, then $f(x)$ is called a transcendental function. However, by this definition, then the following functions are transcendental
$$f(x) = \pi$$
$$f(x) = \pi x$$
$$f(x) = x + \pi$$
so the concept of a transcendental function doesn't seem to be useful as it appears. For example, saying $\log(x)$ is a transcendental function does not mean that there is no non-zero polynomial $P$ such that $P(\log(x),x) = 0$ as we can easily see how that is not true for the functions above.
Now let a strictly transcendental function $f(x)$ be an analytic function such that "there is no non-zero polynomial $P$ such that $P(f(x),x) = 0$". That is, the coefficients can be transcendental. My question is: Is this subclass of transcendental studied anywhere in the literature? Additionally, is there an effective method of proving whether a function falls into this subclass of transcendental functions?

The answer to your final question is a definite "No". If we had such a method, we could apply it to $x + e+\pi$ and finally decide whether $e+\pi$ was transcendental or not. But this is still an open question. Part of the reason for the narrower definition of algebraic, leading to the broader class of trancendental functions is that your functions carry algebraic numbers to transcendental numbers. That is, they do not restrict to functions from algebraic numbers to algebraic numbers.
